# Eclipse `sysout` snippet/expansion to System.out.printf?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to configure my Eclipse preferences to allow me to type:

```
printf<CTRL+SPACE> (or ALT+/, or anything I use as a "Content Assist" sequence)
```

and get this:

```
System.out.printf("<BANANA>%n", <argument1>);
```

with the ability to TAB-jump between `<BANANA>` and `<argument1>`.

The last part is important, the TAB-jump/replace. Notice the selected text would *not* include the %n constant, that stays.

I guess to know this I would need to know how to specify snippets, how to use the built-in variables and convert that into an entry in an `.epf` file.

Also, Eclipse seems to be *wicked* smart in figuring out from the surrounding context which variable I may want in a certain place. Probably from the type, the line proximity, whatever. Do I have any control on that myself when defining a snippet? Example:

```
System.out.printf("<BANANA>%n", <argument1>);
// Make BANANA equal to the second public static final String from the top + " split"
// Make argument1 the closest Float in the current block or any other Double, anywhere
```

Comment: You certainly won't be able to specify anything as granular as you're asking about, nor am I sure that anything like that would be a good idea. It might be able to do something from the format string and args, but I don't know if it actually *does*. Code snippet variables are just $variableName and some predefined ones; I don't know if Eclipse jumps "back and forth" (cycles through them?). Have you looked at the help? IIRC it's all quite straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have what I need now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed something "like" this in an .epf file:

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.custom_templates=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8" standalone\="no"?><templates><template autoinsert\="true" context\="java" deleted\="false" description\="System.out.printf" enabled\="true" name\="pf">System.out.printf("${Message}%n", ${argument1\:var}${cursor});</template></templates>
```

Cursor after first argument to easily add the eventual argument2, ...

What's missing is a way to specify choice among a set, e.g. "choose one of %s, %d, %f, ..."